# Filling matrix in R without for loops

Tags: r, matrix

I am a beginner in R and i know the way i have done is wrong and slow. I would like to fill a matrix and i need to compute each term. I have tried two for loops, here is the code. Do you know a better way to do it?

```
KernelGaussianMatrix <- function(x,delta){
  Mat = matrix(0,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(x))
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
   for (j in 1:length(x)){
     Mat[i,j] = KernelGaussian(x[i],x[j],delta)   
   } 
  } 
  return(Mat)
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to use the function `outer` as in:

```
Mat <- outer(x,x,KernelGaussian,delta)
```

note that any arguments after the third argument in `outer` are provided as additional arguments to the function provided as the third argument to `outer`

Answer (score 0):

If a for loop is required to generate the values than your method is fine.

If the values are already in an array `values` you can try `mat = matrix(values, nrow=n, ncol=p)` or something similar.